# can't connect to the server after deployed rails app in EC2 with Rubber

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2

I just deployed the rails app with Rubber on EC2.Additionally a RDS instance is created for the database. Run

```
$ cat /etc/host
```

to get the rubber config on production as[image]

But when I browse http://web01.musemebackend.com/admin/login, I got the error of '504 Gateway Time-out, server didn't respond in time'

The error log in apache2 shows:

```
[ pid=1813 thr=12161140 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-03-06 20:49:28.175 ]: 
*** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'musemedb.cfmz4gvshyts.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110) (Mysql2::Error)) (process 1813, thread #<Thread:0x000000017320e8>):
```

As I modified the config/database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: muse_me_backend_production
  username: app_admin
  password: MYPASSWORD
  host: musemedb.cfmz4gvshyts.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
```

modified config/rubber/rubber-mysql.yml as:

```
# REQUIRED: The credentials for creating/accessong your app's database
#
db_user: app_admin
db_pass: MYPASSWORD
db_name: muse_me_backend_production
db_host: musemedb.cfmz4gvshyts.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

and config/rubber/common/database.yml as

```
<%
  @path = "#{Rubber.root}/config/database.yml"
%>

<%= Rubber.env %>:
  adapter: <%= YAML::load(File.open("#{Rubber.root}/config/database.yml"))["production"]["adapter"] %>
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= rubber_env.db_name %>
  username: <%= rubber_env.db_user %>
  password: <%= rubber_env.db_pass %>
  host: <%= rubber_env.db_host %>
  pool: 5
```

The app should be deployed successfully. Database migrations are raked successfully too. Are there anything I missed to connect the server? Do I need to own the domain name of musemebackend.com? Now I don't own it. I saw in tutorial it was just foo.com. Does that matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add the security group of the app role instance to DB security group. Now it was fixed.